# Approach to load testing iOS app

Tags: ios, testing, load-testing

I did a search on this but couldn't find a match, possibly due to several meanings of the phrase "load testing"... but what we are trying to do is to make sure our App (which is a medical device that MUST display updated data in a timely fashion) will process data at a required throughput, even if the iPhone gets busy -- e.g., if there are a bunch of apps open that require CPU attention.

The best test approach we can come up with is basically that... open a bunch of apps, and perhaps try to load the CPU by sending it a bunch of emails with large attachments.

But obviously that is just kind of a stab at the risk.  Are there any better techniques out there, or tools?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well that's a somewhat terrifying question. I'm going to hope that you're working from a very lenient definition of "MUST" here given that you're building an app on a general purpose rather than real time operating system. The OS can offer its best effort to give you CPU time and other resources but there are no guarantees and resource contention or thread starvation risks will always be present. If delays in obtaining or rendering data are going to pose a real risk to someone's health please stop and reconsider your approach.

Comment: I worked on a medical thermometer that was iPhone powered. There's guidelines you need to adhere to, and testing plans you need to follow to make it FDA approved. The combination of phone, OS, and device was considered a medical device. Really scary/interesting at the same time.

Comment: But yes, MUST is a very scary word in Software Development. Especially when talking about data transfer or app stability. I suggest running your Quality Control plan and Test Cases by whoever handles Regulatory Quality Control. I suggest understanding that at any time, your app may shut down, just like in a traditional medical device, it may explode for some abnormal reason. Come prepared with a knowledge of the worst case scenarios. (And if all is well, feel free to use my answer to guide your test plan approaches)

Comment: "MUST" = it must be timely OR self-diagnose any latency, and present an error message so that the user knows there is a problem.  We deal with that using application-level timestamps and timestamp checks.  Any busy-ness with iOS (or any other link in the chain) will be flagged and the user will fall back to an analog system.  This is all thoroughly risk-analyzed per FDA regs and IEC-62304.

Comment: What we are doing now is trying to test those self-diagnostic functions as realistically as possible.  To see if we can trip those functions by creating busy-ness in the iPad.  My question is towards how to create that iOS busy-ness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the perspective of your app development, you need to focus on fixing:

- "*What happens when data doesn't send?*"
- "*What happens when the app gets closed by iOS for whatever reason?*"

**There's a million ways to create scenarios that will cause bad cases to happen. Knowing you are covered from general failure is the safest thing to rely on.**

---

From the perspective of validating an existing app:

In past scenarios, when I haven't had control over the development of the app, I've tested these scenarios through manual exploratory testing on physical devices.

Nowadays **the iPhone Simulator now provides lots of utilities so that you may not need to do this all manually.** Scroll to the bottom for these answers.

---

## Testing when the device doesn't reliably transfer data

- **Nontechnical way:** Go on 3G and Airplane mode and toggle connectivity frequently as you use the app.
- **More technial way:** set your phone up to proxy through your computer. Throttle the connection. [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/overview/) does this.

As you throttle the connection, use the app to do any transactions that talk to the backend.

Do they get sent correctly once you reconnect to Wi-Fi or a more stable Wireless connection?

---

## Testing when the CPU is overloaded

- Get the oldest phone that supports your highest target OS (e.g. iPhone 4S on iOS 9) and open a few games in the background.
- Use your app for about 30 minutes aggressively.

  - By aggressively I mean, pretend to be an impatient user that taps 5 times on every button and everywhere else on the screen until you start to notice slowness.
- Exploit the areas that seem to cause the slowness.

Hot spots are: animations, videos, things that cause data to go to the backend, tableviews, collection views, etc.

- See what happens to the app when it crashes.

  - Did you get logged out?
  - Was any key data malformed or lost?

---

## Using the simulator for these things

A note about using the simulator.

The simulator is a convenient way to simulate memory warnings and you can throttle your connection with Charles, or force a reboot. But the CPU will not be throttled in the same way as if you tested on a physical device.

That aside, see the below screenshots for what options are available on the simulator that might help you.

[image: Force reboot or memory warning]

[image: Trigger iCloud Sync]

Hope this helps!